# Select rows where only one column has a value and all other columns have NA

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I would like to know how to get rows based on missing values on multiple columns.

Can `is.na()` be used for this purpose?

My dataset looks like this:

| NO | grade | level | score | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C | D |
| 2 | NA | A | NA | NA |
| 3 | i | j | NA | NA |
| 4 | W | NA | NA | NA |
| 5 | e | f | g | h |
| 6 | NA | A | NA | S |
| 7 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 8 | NA | NA | NA | B |

Firstly, I would like to get like below, where 3 columns have `NA`:

| NO | grade | level | score | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | NA | A | NA | NA |
| 4 | W | NA | NA | NA |
| 8 | NA | NA | NA | B |

Secondly, I would like to get like below, where 2 columns have `NA`:

| NO | grade | level | score | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | i | j | NA | NA |
| 6 | NA | A | NA | S |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is.na` is indeed useful, and we could use it with `rowSums`, `filter`, and `across`:

**(1)**

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  filter(rowSums(is.na(across(grade:class))) == 3)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 5
     NO grade level score class
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     2 NA    A     NA    NA   
2     4 W     NA    NA    NA   
3     8 NA    NA    NA    B
```

**(2)**

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  filter(rowSums(is.na(across(grade:class))) == 2)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 5
     NO grade level score class
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     3 i     j     NA    NA   
2     6 NA    A     NA    S
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rowSums(!is.na(across(...))) == n` to select rows which have exact `n` **non-missing** values.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(rowSums(!is.na(across(-NO))) == 1)
```

---

This answer is similar with (and few minutes earlier than) @harre's but has opposite logic. We select rows which have exact `n` missing & non-missing values respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `rowSums`:

```r
df[rowSums(is.na(df)) == 3, ]

  NO grade level score class
2  2  <NA>     A  <NA>  <NA>
4  4     W  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8  8  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     B
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `NO` is always not missing, you could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(rowSums(!is.na(.)) == 2)
```

Output:

```
  NO grade level score class
1  2  <NA>     A  <NA>  <NA>
2  4     W  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3  8  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     B
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
lapply(3:2, \(x, y) df[x==y,], rowSums(is.na(df[-1])))

[[1]]
  NO grade level score class
2  2  <NA>     A  <NA>  <NA>
4  4     W  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8  8  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     B

[[2]]
  NO grade level score class
3  3     i     j  <NA>  <NA>
6  6  <NA>     A  <NA>     S
```